# Congruence cancellation [in Hensel lifting a square root to a $p$-adic root]

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In the book of [Z.I._Borevitch,_I.R._Chafarevitch]_Théorie_des_nombres p.21 the authors talking about the construction of 7-adic integers by considering equations of type
$$(C_n): x^2\equiv 2\mod 7^n$$
for $n=1$ the solution satisfy $x_0\equiv \pm 3\mod 7$. For $n=2$,  the solutions $(C_2)$ are in the solutions of $(C_1)$ so he considers those of the form $x_1=3+7t_1$, and replacing in $(C_2)$ implies
\begin{align*}
(3+7t_1)^2&\equiv 2\mod 7^2\\
9+6.7t_1+7^2t_1^2&\equiv 2\mod 7^2\\
1+6t_1&\equiv 0\mod 7\\
\end{align*}
For me it is not understood why $1+6t_1\equiv 0\mod 7$ ? this is my problem.

Comment: $$  7 + 6 \cdot 7 t_1 + 7^2 t_1^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{7^2}, $$ $$  7 + 6 \cdot 7 t_1    \equiv 0 \pmod{7^2}, $$  $$  7 (1 + 6 \cdot  t_1)    \equiv 0 \pmod{7^2}, $$

Comment: $\begin{align} &\bmod 7\cdot\color{#c00}7\!:\  {-}\color{#c00}7\equiv  6t\cdot \color{#c00}7 + \overbrace{7^2 t^2}^{\equiv\ 0}\\[.2em] \Longrightarrow\ &\bmod 7\!:\ \ \ \,\ \ {-}1\equiv 6t,\ \text{ by cancel $\color{#c00}7$ as in the linked dupe}\end{align}$

Comment: Any thoughts about the comment and answers, Muhammad?

Comment: @GerryMyerson very clear thanks.

Comment: If one of the answers was satisfactory, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

As an intermediate step between your second and third displayed congruences, we have $(9-2)+6\cdot 7\cdot t_1 + 7^2\cdot t_1=0 \mod 7^2$. Since $7a=0 \mod 7^2$ implies $a=0\mod 7$ (!), we get $1 + 6t_1+7t_1^2=0\mod 7$. The $7t_1$ term is $0$ mod $7$, so this is $1+6t_1=0\mod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put in some missing steps. From $9+6\cdot7t_1+7^2t_1^2\equiv2\bmod{7^2}$ we subtract $2$ to get
$7+6\cdot7t_1+7^2t_1^2\equiv0\bmod{7^2}$ then we divide through by $7$ to get
$1+6t_1+7t_1^2\equiv0\bmod{7}$   and that gets you
$1+6t_1\equiv0\bmod{7}$.